# MySQL ORDER BY key-value pairs key being primary key

Tags: mysql, redis, sql-order-by

I'm wondering if there's any easy way to order MySQL select results by using key-value pairs provided as query parameters?

I have a query that currently calculates the order by sorting on multiple columns, some of them calculated on-the-fly (count of rows from related table) and it's quite slow. I can't cache the whole result, because there are plenty of other filters that may be applied to this query. I thought of generating cache for sorting, since I do not require this to change that often (It would invalidate periodically). I would like to store this order in Redis. So I would have something like this (ID:order - higher is better):

- 1:39
- 2:37
- 3:34

Is there any way to accomplish it? Or perhaps just store sorted array of IDs (without order, it seems redundant here). and use in similar manner?

## EDIT

I have found function `FIELD(<field>, values ...)` which is probably what I need. I think I will have to test it first to see whether it ovecomes my issue with long query time (since I also read `FIELD` is rather slow too).

Comment: you probably want to perform this sort of ordering in your application code rather

Comment: @Rahul this can't be done, because the result uses `LIMIT` to split data in pages and thus it hast to be sorted before the results are returned from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after my findings regarding `FIELD` function of MySQL I decided to test it and that was it.

Since the bottleneck of my query was amount of data in related table the count was performed on, the quick growth of that table kept making the query slower and slower. Now, that I eliminated the related table from my query. I instead generate the order (using the original query) in background and cache the ordered set of IDs matching PK of table I need to sort.

Because new query does not "touch" the related table it only depends on speed of `FIELD` function and amount of rows in the "root" table of the query, which is pretty much constant.

I managed to achieve 3000% query speed improvement (1.5s~ to 0.05s~) by doing that.